# biblatex: How to set citation options per citation command?

Tags: biblatex, author-number

In the `alphabetic` style, I am using `maxcitenames=4` and `minnames=3` as global options. However, when using `\textcite` instead of `\cite`, these settings are pretty unreasonable, and I want it to behave as if `maxcitenames=3` and `minnames=1` were set. How do I achieve this?

To be more specific, in the example below I want

```
\cite{ABCDE}
```

to produce

> [ABG+01]

, and

```
\textcite{ADCDE}
```

to produce

> Alpha, *et al.* [ABG+01]

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ style=alphabetic, maxcitenames=4, minnames=3 ]{biblatex}

% set \textcite option maxcitenames=3 and minnames=1 here

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ABCDE,
  author = {Alpha, A. and Beta, B. and Gamma, G. and Delta, D. and Epsilon, E.},
  year = 2001
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{ABCDE}
\textcite{ABCDE}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With biber this can be handled by the following option settings.

```
maxcitenames=3,minnames=1,maxalphanames=4,minalphanames=3
```

With BibTeX you can define variants of existing citation commands in your document preamble.

```
\newbool{cbx:resetnames}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifbool{cbx:resetnames}
    {\defcounter{minnames}{1}\defcounter{maxnames}{3}}
    {}}

\let\origtextcite\textcite
\renewrobustcmd{\textcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\booltrue{cbx:resetnames}}\origtextcite}

\let\origtextcites\textcites
\renewrobustcmd{\textcites}{%
  \AtNextCite{\booltrue{cbx:resetnames}}\origtextcites}

\let\origciteauthor\citeauthor
\renewrobustcmd{\citeauthor}{%
  \AtNextCite{\booltrue{cbx:resetnames}}\origciteauthor}
```

Note that since `minnames` and `maxnames` are entry-specific options, they must be reset using an entry-specific hook like `\AtEveryCitekey`.

Comment: How can your second approach be adjusted for `fullcite` or `footfullcite`?

Comment: @sebschub I've revised the second approach. It should work with any citation command, including multi-citation commands.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks a lot, I adopted your approach to my needs!

Answer (score 5):

You can define a new command using `\AtNextCite` and setting the `maxnames`, `minnames` counters to the desired values; something along the lines illustrated in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ style=alphabetic, maxcitenames=4, minnames=3 ]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd{\TExtcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{3}\defcounter{minnames}{1}}\textcite}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ABCDE,
  author = {Alpha, A. and Beta, B. and Gamma, G. and Delta, D. and Epsilon, E.},
  year = 2001
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ABCDE}

\TExtcite{ABCDE}    

\textcite{ABCDE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to work with biblatex 2.7: your `\TExtcite` yields the same result as \textcite. Any suggestions?

Comment: @sebschub Try Audrey's answer.

Comment: @sebschub This answer was always a bit of a cheat - it never worked when processing more than one entry. This is because `minnames` and friends are set-able per entry; the values should really be set via a key-specific hook. As of 2.7, `\textcite` in most standard styles processes each entry at least twice, so resetting the counters via `\AtNextCite` won't work at all.