# biblatex: DOI for just one citation

Tags: biblatex, doi

I want to have the DOI field explicitly printed for just one (or two) citations (`\fullfootcite` in my case). For the rest of the document, I use the `doi=false` option of biblatex combined with a [DOI link included in the title of the reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48400/11605). The other questions about per citation options found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12846/11605) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75043/11605) are only concerned with modifying the number of printed author names.

Comment: Why not skip an explicit call to `\fullfootcite` and simply use `\citefield{<entry key>}{doi}` along with `\fullcite` in a `\footnote` command?

Comment: @jon That's certainly a possibility, I didn't know the `\citefield` command. However, it would be interesting to know whether there is a more general solution which does not include the manual workaround.

Comment: Well, rather than fiddle with a basic citation command for what you consider to be an *exception* to the normal operation of things, I think it is better to wrap my suggestion into a custom command of your own (which I should perhaps have mentioned explicitly), or by using `biblatex`'s `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

Comment: @jon Because `\citefield` doesn't apply the same format as the bibliography driver. The user would also have to replicate the driver's order and unit punctuation. Small changes to existing citation commands are best handled using the citation hooks. For big changes `\DeclareCiteCommand` should almost always be preferred over generic LaTeX commands.

Comment: @Audrey -- I agree that using `biblatex` methods is usually the better way forward (and +1 for your simple and elegant answer), but if one is globally turning off the `DOI` field, there is no a priori reason to assume that the bibliography driver is doing or even needs to be doing the 'right thing' with the formatting of the `DOI` field.  Thus the simpler, and perhaps much faster (depending on one's knowledge of `biblatex`), though certainly less cleaner, solution may be to use a low-level command for what amounts to an ad hoc problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `standard.bbx` it is apparent that the `doi` option setting toggles the value of `bbx:doi`. Loading biblatex with `doi=false` essentially invokes `\togglefalse{bbx:doi}`. To enable `doi` for just a few `\fullfootcite` commands, use:

```
\AtNextCite{\toggletrue{bbx:doi}}\fullfootcite{<keys>}
```

Note that use of `\AtNextCite` is appropriate here because the scope of `doi` is global. Scope of all standard options can be found in the biblatex manual appendix called "Option Scope".

Comment: @sebschub As a regular user of FontPro, this is the least I could do.